# What is flutter_secure_storage exactly and how it works?

Tags: flutter

i work on authentification for my app now. I have heard good things about flutter_secure_storage but i would like to know how it works exactly because i am not sure. I have read it stores data in shared préférences but all data are crypted which would be great for what i need to do. Is it true ? And is it really secure ? Can i store the username and password with it with security ? Can we imagine a user log in my app and i store all with this plugin flutter_secure_storage (example : i can store the email or the id of the member crypted so when the user go back on the app if i find the value crypted in shared préférences i redirect him to member page and so i know the member's id in the app when i need it

Comment: As mentioned in the package description, the datas are stored in Keychain for iOS and Keystore for Android. So, yes, it's secure. You can read more info about those two storage by clicking on their respective links in https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Comment: Thank for answer :) It works on all mobile phone you think ? Because i have seen it "Note KeyStore was introduced in Android 4.3 (API level 18). The plugin wouldn't work for earlier versions.". If yes, you think we can use it for store sensible data like username, password or Something like that ?

Comment: Yes the plugin will work on all Android devices starting with the API 18. Targeting Android devices under the API 18 remain your choice. Today, it represent a low percentage of people.

Comment: i use android studio for dev, do you think the emulator will work for all the test with flutter secure storage ???

Comment: If your emulator runs on API 18 or higher, yes absolutely.
Android is now on API 29 and devices lower than API 18 represents less than 3 percent of all devices on the world. (https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards)

Comment: ok so it is great :) So if i use 1 email and password for log in. How you think i need use this plugin exactly. I have seen all game apps need just a signup and after no need to log in the app. Log in page is only for people who have delete the app and have an account so when they set up the app they need to log in. Do you think i can just store a member id the api will return me during the signup ? So when the user launch the app, i look for the member id in flutter_secure_storage and if there is here i log the user to his account. Can you explain me the best solution for you ?

Comment: FirebaseAuth package is what you want (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth).
Read the documentation. it's well documented

Comment: firebase_auth is not free no ???

Comment: Yes it's free ;) there is a lot of documentation including pricing. You will have to read a lot ^^

Comment: i have read but it is not clear, i have seen it is not really free to use. Firebase is not free at all normally it was the Reason i haven't work with it

Comment: and i am french it is not easy understand English perfectly :(

Comment: so for doing authentication by email/password i need to take Spark Plan which is free on firebase. If i understand well firebase is free for a lot of functions. But where are the datas exactly ??? When a user signup, the data like email and password are stored where exactly ??? I am not sure to understand well

Comment: Sorry, but I can't spend more time to explain everything to you. You have to read the documentation or articles on the web. I'm sure you'll find everything you want to know 

Answer (score 8):

So i decided to user flutter_secure_storage and i do ot like that :

```
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read value

mail = await storage.read(key: "e");
pass = await storage.read(key: "p");
```

And for write the keys when signup or login i do it :

```
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
await storage.write(key: "e", value: email);
await storage.write(key: "p", value: password);
```

It seems very simple and it works but i Don't understand how it can be crypted. From my side i crypt Nothing i set the email and password
How it works exactly ?

Comment: If device is android then flutter_secure_storage library store data in encryptedSharedPreference which is android specific shared prference where key values store in encrypted format. 
If deice is iOS then flutter_secure_storage library store data in Keychain which is iOS specific storage where key values store in encrypted format and which is accessible only by your app.

Comment: how's the encryption key been generating? can we pass our own?

Comment: @eternalStudent - I don't have a comprehensive explanation but I can share some light on the linux implementation of flutter_secure_storage. They define a SecretStorage class in the Secret.hpp file (https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/flutter_secure_storage_linux/linux/include/Secret.hpp). It uses GNOME's libsecret's secret.h [2] (https://github.com/GNOME/libsecret/blob/master/libsecret/secret.h) to encrypt and store the key-value pairs in JSON format. (see the storeToKeyring method for implementation details)

Comment: The storage algorithm depends on the platform, for example for Windows the credential storage has been used (the WinAPI methods like CredRead, CredWrite...). You can check the sources: https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage